# How to read git command options

Tags: git, documentation

Whenever I need to learn more about a git command I run into the documentation which is helpful but I don't understand the particular syntax that is used to describe the possible options.

For example

```
git help [-a|--all] [-g|--guide]
       [-i|--info|-m|--man|-w|--web] [COMMAND|GUIDE]
```

What is this formatting or syntax called ? 
I can infer that `[a|--all]` means `-a or --all`.

I don't understand why some options are separated and some are grouped into square brackets.

This is a simple example there are more complicated commands.

I tried using git help help but I didn't find anything useful (unless I missed something).

Comment: This is a common convention where optional arguments are placed in `[]`. Required arguments are often `UPPER CASE` but are not placed in `[]` unless there are multiple options like in this case `COMMAND` or `GUIDE`. There is no standard on how commands should give help but this is a common convention on *nix.

Comment: Actually the Git documentation can be pretty cryptic, and Stack Overflow is a good place to see how to use a given command.

Comment: @Tatsh When using `git help` is the required option `COMMAND` or `GUIDE` automatically inputed ? I ask this because I don't need to input it when calling `git help`.

Comment: I just read that a synopsis is given if no required argument are given.

Answer (score 1):

`[]` means the option is optional

`[a|b|c..|d]` means any of the `a`, `b`, `c`, .., or `d` can be used for this particular option.

So if you want to see all the available commands use

`git help -a` or `git help --all`

Comment: In this example [-i|--info|-m|--man|-w|--web], can only one of these be used at a time ? You said that enclosed commands can be used for an option, so I'm guessing only one at a time.

Comment: You can put multiple, it will pick the first one that matches.

Comment: That makes more sense. Is there ever a situation where multiple options can be selected or is it always one at a time ?

Comment: Check this: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-help . You will get to know which command overrides others and how they work together.